# nginx location pointing to an ip instead of a folder

Tags: wordpress, laravel, nginx, nginx-location

So I have a website running on [laravel](https://laravel.com/) in `http://example.com` sitting on `server-A` having a `111.111.111.111` ip and I have a [wordpress](https://wordpress.com/) sitting on `server-B` having a `222.222.222.222`

I want it so that I can access my wordpress through `http://example.com/mywordpress`

how can I achieve this? I tried googling but I cant seem to get the keyword right

for now this is the best thing I can come up with

```
# my nginx conf

location /mywordpress {
  proxy_pass http://mywordpress.example.com/; //already set the 222.222.222.222 to server-B
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that you have a /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com on server-A

open and add this line :

```
location /mywordpress {
    proxy_pass http://222.222.222.222/mywordpress;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

after

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

on server-B
assuming that you had your wordpress installed on your root /var/www/html and only wordpress files existed

follow this guide https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

create new directory /var/www/html/mywordpress

move all your files from /var/www/html to /var/www/html/mywordpress

copy index.php and .htaccess from mywordpress directory to your html folder

edit the /var/www/html/index.php

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

to

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/mywordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

and now, try accesing your new example.com/mywordpress

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
http {

    upstream wordpress {
         server 222.222.222.222:80 max_fails=2  fail_timeout=3s;
    }

    server {

        listen 80;

        server_name example.com;

        location /mywordpress {
             rewrite /mywordpress(.*) /$1  break;
             proxy_pass http://wordpress
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i did try something like this (and changed the site url in wordpress to match server-A) but it ended up doing a redirect loop when accessing anything inside /mywordpress/*, any ideas?